# Correctly Using ACS712 hooked to a microcontroller

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, mains

I am making a project that involves AC current measurement from the Mains. I have done a bit of research and have found that the ACS712 can do this.

I would like to know the correct way of using this module so that it outputs analog data that my microcontroller can read(I would like to get the total WATTS) .

I will use [THIS](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-design-30A-range-Current-Sensor-Module-ACS712-Module-Arduino-module-/310506962976?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item484ba84020). I am assuming that incoming current will go to one of the screws, and the wire connected to the load , to the other one(correct me if i am wrong)

I read somewhere that capacitors are needed. Please tell me how, and why. 
Also tell me if the ground pin needs to be connected from the ground of the mains

Answer (score 2):

Before any testing, prevent touching the pcb accidentally by packing the module in a suitable plastic box.
The ACS series convert current[AMPERES].
If you need power[watts] measurement you need to add a voltage measurement and do some extra calculations in the controller.
The two screws are MAIN-side.
Capacitors are needed to adjust filtering behaviour.
The ground from the mains is not needed for the current-measurement.
The ground pin from the mains should be used, for safety reason, to ground all outer metal parts that can accidentally contact one of the main wires.